# Getting the inverse of a 2d polynomial transform with numpy (for image or raster image warping/sampling)

Tags: numpy, image-processing, gis, transform, linear-algebra

If I have a 2-dimensional (x and y coordinates) polynomial transform function of 1st/affine, 2nd, or 3rd order (i.e. I have the coefficients/transformation matrix `A`), what is the mathematical or programmatic approach to getting the exact inverse of this function? Ideally, how would I implement this in Numpy? This is in the context of image warping or map georeferencing, i.e. transforming or warping the coordinates from an input image to an output image in a new warped coordinate system.

### Attempted Solution

To solve this I have tried a matrix algebra approach for solving sets of equations. Mathematically, the transformation procedure is represented as `Au = v`. Forward transforming is easy, where you calculate `u` as a column-matrix containing the terms of the polynomial equation based on your input coordinates, and then matrix-multiply `u` with the transformation matrix `A`, in order to get the transformed output column matrix `v` containing the output coordinates. Backwards transforming on the other hand, means we know the output coordinates `v` and want to find the input coordinates `u`, so we need to reshuffle our equation as `u = Av`. By the rules of matrix algebra, the `A` matrix has to be inverted when moving it over. Implementing this in Numpy for a 2nd order polynomial transform, it does seem to work:

```
import numpy as np

# input coords
x = np.array([13])
y = np.array([13])
    
# terms of the 2nd order polynomial equation
x = x
y = y
xx = x*x
xy = x*y
yy = y*y
ones = np.ones(x.shape)

# u consists of each term in 2nd order polynomial equation
# with each term being array if want to transform multiple
u = np.array([xx,xy,yy,x,y,ones])
print('original input u', u)

## output:
## ('original input u', array([[169.],
##       [169.],
##       [169.],
##       [ 13.],
##       [ 13.],
##       [  1.]]))

# forward transform matrix
A = np.array([[1,2,3,1,6,8],
              [5,2,9,2,0,1],
              [8,1,5,8,4,3],
              [1,4,8,2,3,9],
              [9,3,2,1,9,5],
              [4,2,5,6,2,1]])

# get forward coords
v = A.dot(u)
print('output v', v)

## output:
## ('output v', array([[1113.],
##       [2731.],
##       [2525.],
##       [2271.],
##       [2501.],
##       [1964.]]))

# get backward coords (should exactly reproduce the input coords)
Ainv = np.linalg.inv(A)
u_pred = Ainv.dot(v)
print('backwards predicted input u', u_pred)

## output:
## ('backwards predicted input u', array([[169.],
##       [169.],
##       [169.],
##       [ 13.],
##       [ 13.],
##       [  1.]]))
```

In the above example the output `v` is actually a 1x6 matrix, where only the top two rows/values represent the transformed x and y coordinates. The problem becomes that we need *all* the additional values in `v` in order to exactly inverse the coordinates. But in real-world scenarios we only know transformed x and y values (i.e. the top two rows/values of `v`), we don't know the full 1x6 `v` matrix.

Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong, or maybe this matrix algebra approach is not the right approach, since 2nd order polynomials and higher are no longer linear? Any alternate programmatic/numpy approaches for inversing the polyonimal transformation?

### Some context

I've looked up many similar questions and websites as well as numpy functions such as `numpy.polynomial.Polynomial.fit`, but most of them relate only to inversing 1-dimensional polynomial transforms. The few links I've found that talk about 2-dimensional transforms say there is no exact way to inverse it, which doesn't make sense since this is a very common operation in image warping/resampling and map georeferencing. For example, the steps for warping an image is often broken down to:

1. Forward project all original pixel (column-row) coordinates `u` using the transformation function/matrix `A`, in order to find the bounds of the transformed coordinate space `v`.
2. Then for every coordinate sampled at regular intervals in the transformed coordinate space bounds (found in step 1), backwards sample these `v` coordinates in the transformed coordinate system to find their original coordinates `u`. This determines which original pixels to sample for each location in the transformed image.

My problem then is that I have the forward transformation necessary for step 1, but I need to find the exact inverse of that transformation necessary for backwards sampling in step 2. Either a math answer or a numpy solution would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Inversion of a 2D affine function is pretty easy. It takes the resolution of a 2x2 linear system of equations.

The case of quadratic and cubic polynomials is much more problematic. If I am right, a system in two unknows is equivalent to a single quartic or nonic (degree 9) polynomial equation. Explicit (though complicated) formulas exist for the quartic case, but none for the nonic case, and you will have to resort to numerical methods (Newton's iterations).

In addition, the solution of these nonlinear equations are not unique (you can have 4 or 9 solutions) and you need to keep the right ones.

---

If your transformation remains close to affine (such as when correcting image distortion), I would suggest to choose an affine transformation that approximates the complete equation, use the backward transformation to find initial approximations, then refine with Newton.

Comment: Correct, the affine transform is the only one I can get to work with a simple inverse of the A matrix. I also suspect the added complexity is because 2nd and 3rd order polys may bend the image back on itself, such that a pixel in the original image may transform to multiple possible locations in the warped image. Does it help to add some assumptions, e.g. the original image pixel coordinates are guaranteed to be only positive numbers?

Comment: Also, does this mean that inverting 2nd order polys simply is not done in practice then? I do know that map georeferencing/rectifying often uses 2nd or 3rd order polys, I'm just not sure how they invert the transform for backwards pixel resampling...